# Using json2html but can't see JSON objects

Tags: json, mongodb

I've been working to implement json2html in a project I'm working on and I'm running into a little issue. Basically, my transform runs but it isn't including the JSON objects like it should be.

I have things set up so that a call is made to MongoDB and JSON data is returned as a string. I pass that string into "var data", which is then passed into json2html.transform(data,transform) with my transform code.

Here is a sample of my transform code:

transform =[

```
{"tag":"html","children":[
    {"tag":"body","children":[
                     {"tag":"p","html":"First Name: ${firstName}"},
         {"tag":"p","html":"Last Name: ${lastName}"},
            ]}
    ]}
```

];

...and the corresponding JSON data from MongoDB...

{ biographicData:
   { firstName: 'John',
     lastName: 'Doe',
     birthDate: '10/15/1983',
     email: 'johndoe@gmail.com',
     workPhone: '678-901-2345',
     mobilePhone: '098-765-4321',
     homePhone: '123-456-7890' }
}

...but my HTML comes out looking like this:

First Name:

Last Name:

The JSON objects are nowhere to be found. Any idea what might be the issue here?

Comment: try ${biographicData.firstName}

Comment: I've made the change you suggested, but unfortunately I'm still not seeing the JSON objects. Just the html tags and the plain text within them.

Comment: pass in the embedded object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom had it right .. ${biographicData.whatever} should have fixed the issue.  Try this code spinet which will work

```
var data = { biographicData: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', birthDate: '10/15/1983', email: 'johndoe@gmail.com', workPhone: '678-901-2345', mobilePhone: '098-765-4321', homePhone: '123-456-7890' } };

var transform = {"tag":"html","children":[
    {"tag":"body","children":[
                     {"tag":"p","html":"First Name: ${biographicData.firstName}"},
         {"tag":"p","html":"Last Name: ${biographicData.lastName}"},
            ]}
    ]};

document.write(json2html.transform(data,transform));
```

I would recommend however that you remove the html & body tag from the transform and instead include it in the html file it's self. That way you can pass along an array of values like this

```
var data = [{ biographicData: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', birthDate: '10/15/1983', email: 'johndoe@gmail.com', workPhone: '678-901-2345', mobilePhone: '098-765-4321', homePhone: '123-456-7890' } }];

    var transform = [
             {"tag":"p","html":"First Name: ${biographicData.firstName}"},
             {"tag":"p","html":"Last Name: ${biographicData.lastName}"},   
     ];

    document.write(json2html.transform(data,transform));
```

Otherwise you'll end up with multiple html & head tags in your resulting html

Comment: Hey Chad. I tried adjusting my code to what you have in your second block, but I'm still seeing the same issue. All of the HTML tags and the plaintext render correctly, but no JSON objects. And I've corrected the naming issue pointed out by both you and Tom above so that now it reads ${biographicData.whatever}.

Comment: So clearly the transform is working, and I know I'm returning the JSON data because I'm able to print it out in the console and it looks right. But the two don't seem to work together properly.

Comment: best to recreate the issue on jsfiddle and post up the link here .. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So it turns out there was just an issue with how my JSON data was being passed into json2html.transform. When my JSON data was being returned from MongoDB, it was going into "data", but in order for it to work properly in the transform, I had to set it as json2html.transform(JSON.stringify(data), transform). But the suggestion that both you and Tom made above to correct the naming of the data was essential as well, so thank you both for that.